# How can we say that a gene is spacio-temporally regulated?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, gene-expression

Gene expression is depending on the space and time of the cell. How can we distinguish the function of a gene without a chance of changing its expression? And also how is it possible to find the exact position where the gene is expressed?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to fit with the body of the question, which includes two almost completely unrelated subquestions. Can you edit to clarify and reduce your question to one question? It would also help to describe your attempts to answer the question on your own. A typical basic biology textbook would have examples of both testing function and measuring location while teaching other concepts.

Comment: Some clarifying questions:  *"How can we distinguish the function of a gene without a chance of changing its expression."* -- are you asking what the effects of measurement are on transcriptional dynamics? *"And also how is it possible to find the exact position where the gene is expressed?"* -- by *position*, are you referring to position in the nucleus / cell?  position along the gene body?